# Wire guage needed for adding a 100 amp breaker box in garage

Tags: wiring, cables, aluminum-wiring

I'm running a wire buried wire from my indoor breaker box to an indoor breaker box in my detached garage. I have a 200 amp main breaker box but in the garage I am using a 100 amp breaker box.

The main question I have is what size breaker will I need to put in the main breaker?

As for the wire between the two, instead of using `3-3-3-5 copper` I want to use `1-1-1-2 aluminum`, would this be sufficient?

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: When you say 1-1-1-3 aluminum, what *type* of cable are you referring to? SER? URD? something else?

Comment: +1 for actually figuring out #1Al/#3Cu is the required size.  Most people rely on "folk knowledge" that claims #2Al/#4Cu is sufficient (it's not; it's only good for 90A).   Note that a 100A feeder needs any breaker box >=100A.  You should avoid 100A boxes because they are notoriously small in terms of number of *breaker spaces*... spaces are cheap, and a 100A feeder can power a heck of a lot more stuff than you think it can.  I wouldn't consider less than a 24-space.  Spaces are cheap, and "help, I'm outta spaces" is the #1 question around here.

Comment: 3-3-3-5  copper?  4 or 6 instead of 5?

Comment: @JACK that's because the people who make multi-conductor cables, don't necessarily follow NEC rules for sizes.